# How to disable button in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class AddItem extends React.Component {

add() {
    this.props.onButtonClick(this.input.value);
    this.input.value = '';
}


render() {
    return (
        <div className="add-item">
            <input type="text" className="add-item__input" ref={(input) => this.input = input} placeholder={this.props.placeholder} />
            <button disabled={!this.input.value} className="add-item__button" onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Add</button>
        </div>
    );
}

}
```

I want the button to be disabled when input value is empty. But the code above doesn't work. It says:

> add-item.component.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

pointing to `disabled={!this.input.value}`. What can I be doing wrong  here? I'm guessing that perhaps ref isn't created yet when `render` method is executed. If, so what is the workararound?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Using `refs` is not best practice because it reads the DOM directly, it's better to use React's `state` instead. Also, your button doesn't change because the component is not re-rendered and stays in its initial state.

You can use `setState` together with an `onChange` event listener to render the component again every time the input field changes:

```js
// Input field listens to change, updates React's state and re-renders the component.
<input onChange={e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })} value={this.state.value} />

// Button is disabled when input state is empty.
<button disabled={!this.state.value} />
```

Here's a working example:

```js
class AddItem extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { value: '' };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
  }

  add() {
    this.props.onButtonClick(this.state.value);
    this.setState({ value: '' });
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="add-item">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="add-item__input"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        />
        <button
          disabled={!this.state.value}
          className="add-item__button"
          onClick={this.add}
        >
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AddItem placeholder="Value" onButtonClick={v => console.log(v)} />,
  document.getElementById('View')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='View'></div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer! Internal state should be used to update on change of the input and the button should simply check against this. +1

Comment: this.state has a limitation that it renders the UI again so if you're typing in a text box in a child component and have bound to the onChange event, it loses focus from the textbox. If it's in the same component it's fine but when used in a child component it loses focus.

Comment: @Dynamic That should not happen. Do you have a working example of that?

Comment: Just FYI this is not cross-browser friendly. Many browsers still interpret the presence of disabled as true even if set to false. Like it literally just checks for presence of attribute disabled. You must remove the disabled attribute to be cross-browser friendly.

Comment: @Adrianopolis React removes the `disabled` attribute from the DOM if it's set to `false`—this is cross-browser friendly.

Comment: Not when you are using it like this: disabled={!this.state.value}

Comment: @Adrianopolis I don't know what to tell you. Check out the actual, running demo code with your inspector. React is removing the `disabled` attribute. This is JSX, not HTML. No issue here.

Comment: @FabianSchultz is this also possible when your state.value = null instead of '' ?

Answer (score 30):

In HTML,

```html
<button disabled/>
<button disabled="true">
<button disabled="false">
<button disabled="21">
```

All of them boils down to `disabled="true"` that is because it returns `true` for a non-empty string.
Hence, in order to return `false`, pass a empty string in a conditional statement like `this.input.value ? "true" : ""`.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="add-item">
            <input
                type="text"
                className="add-item__input"
                ref={(input) => this.input = input}
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            />
            <button 
                disabled={this.input.value ? "true" : ""}
                className="add-item__button"
                onClick={this.add.bind(this)}
            >
                Add
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is `buttton` misspelt here?

Comment: React is different from standard DOM, the disabled property takes an actual boolean in React, so `disabled={true}` or `disabled={false}`.

Comment: Strings are not accepted for `disabled` property. Update- 
`disabled={this.input.value ? true : false}`

Answer (score 13):

Here is a functional component variety using react hooks.

The example code I provided should be generic enough for modification with the specific use-case or for anyone searching "How to disable a button in React" who landed here.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log('Your button was clicked and is now disabled');
    setDisabled(true);
  }

  return (
      <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit} disabled={isDisabled}>
        Submit
      </button>
  );
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Answer (score 7):

There are few typical methods how we control components render in React.
[image]

But, I haven't used any of these in here, I just used the ref's to namespace underlying children to the component.

```js
class AddItem extends React.Component {
    change(e) {
      if ("" != e.target.value) {
        this.button.disabled = false;
      } else {
        this.button.disabled = true;
      }
    }

    add(e) {
      console.log(this.input.value);
      this.input.value = '';
      this.button.disabled = true;
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div className="add-item">
          <input type="text" className = "add-item__input" ref = {(input) => this.input=input} onChange = {this.change.bind(this)} />
          
          <button className="add-item__button" 
          onClick= {this.add.bind(this)} 
          ref={(button) => this.button=button}>Add
          </button>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AddItem / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't be setting the value of the input through refs.

Take a look at the documentation for controlled form components here - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

In a nutshell

```
<input value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => this.setState({value: e.target.value})} />
```

Then you will be able to control the disabled state by using `disabled={!this.state.value}`

Answer (score 6):

very simple solution for this is by using `useRef` hook

```
const buttonRef = useRef();

const disableButton = () =>{
  buttonRef.current.disabled = true; // this disables the button
 }

<button
className="btn btn-primary mt-2"
ref={buttonRef}
onClick={disableButton}
>
    Add
</button>
```

Similarly you can enable the button by using `buttonRef.current.disabled = false`

Answer (score 2):

`this.input` is undefined until the `ref` callback is called. Try setting `this.input` to some initial value in your constructor.

From [the React docs on refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), emphasis mine:

> the callback will be executed immediately **after** the component is mounted or unmounted

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem, turns out we don't need hooks to do these, we can make an conditional render and it will still work fine.

```html
<Button
    type="submit"
    disabled={
        name === "" || email === "" || password === "" 
    }
    fullWidth
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    className={classes.submit}>
    SignUP
</Button>
```

Comment: Cool solution, I did the same

Comment: `? true : false` is unnecessary since `===` already returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [isButtonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () => {
    // Disable the button after performing the action
    setButtonDisabled(true);
};

<button onClick={handleClick} disabled={isButtonDisabled}>
     Click me
</button>
```

The isButtonDisabled state variable is used to keep track of whether the button should be disabled.

The handleClick function is called when the button is clicked. After performing some action, it sets the isButtonDisabled state to true.

The disabled={isButtonDisabled} attribute on the  element ensures that the button is disabled when isButtonDisabled is true.