# How to disable buttons on ReactJS properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning ReactJS. I wrote a web app that should show an input text and a button 'Confirm', and when pressed it shows a second input text with a button 'Go back' which removes the new input. When the second one is showed, the first input and the first button are disabled.

However, my current script is not accepted. I'm having problems with passing functions as prop to the function FormRender and with indicating in the FormRender object itself the property "disabled" (it claims to have found "unexpected token").

Are there any better approaches?

```
function FormRender (props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type = "text" placeholder = {this.props.holder} {this.props.disable} />
            <button onClick = {this.props.Click()} {this.props.disable} > {this.state.value} </button>
        </div>
    );
};

var R  = React.createClass ({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { names: [], disable: false }
    },
    update: function () {
        return this.state.disable ? "disabled" : "";
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var a = this.state.names;
        a.push ( <FormRender holder = 'Name' value = 'Confirm' Click = {this.In}, disable: {this.update} /> );
        this.setState ( { names: a } );
        this.forceUpdate();
    },  
    In: function () {
        var a = this.state.names;
        this.setState ( { disable: true } );
        a.push ( <FormRender holder = 'Surname ' value = 'Back' Click = {this.Out} disable: "" /> );
        this.setState ( { names: a } );
        this.forceUpdate();
    },
    Out: function () {
        var a = this.state.names;
        this.setState ( { disable: false } );
        a.splice(a.length-1,1);
        this.setState ( { names: a } );
        this.forceUpdate();
    },  
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.names}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use `disabled={true/false}`, no need for the string conversion. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41488965/6941627).

Comment: @Roc you have got few mistakes in your code.
1. Functional components haven't got state so:
`{this.state.value}` won't work
2. In FormRender you get access to props by first parameter so don't use `this.props.disable` but 'props.disable'
3. When you assign event handler like `onClick` you should assign function: `onClick={this.props.Click}` (without brackets)
4. When you defining props you cannot use ':' as assign operator. In the most places you use '=' but in few places you use ':'. You must change it.


And probably you should use `Click = {this.In.bind(this)}`

Comment: I forget about your "unexpected token" error. Use `disbale={this.props.disable}` in FormRender.

Comment: @Grajek done, but whatever notation I use for props it won't me allow to use it

Comment: @Roc could you update the code?

Comment: @Grajek I've modified it several times that it would be useless. I've tried assinging first new variables, passing from this.props.holder to props.holder to this.holder to just holder and so on, and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is what you want my example

```
function FormRender (props) {
return (
    <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder={props.holder}
            disabled={props.disable()}
        />
        <button
            onClick={props.click}
            disabled={props.disable()}
        >
            {props.value}
        </button>
    </div>
);
};

var R  = React.createClass ({
getInitialState: function () {
    return {names: [], disable: false}
},

update: function () {
    return this.state.disable;
},

componentDidMount: function () {
    var a = this.state.names;
    var form = {
        holder: 'Name',
        value: 'Confirm',
        click: this.In,
        disable: this.update
    };

    a.push(form);
    this.setState({names: a});
},  
In: function () {
    if (this.state.names.length > 1) {
        return;
    }

    var a = this.state.names;
    var form = {
        holder: 'Surname',
        value: 'Back',
        click: this.Out,
        disable: function () {
            return false
        }
    }

    this.setState({disable: true});
    a.push(form);
    this.setState({names: a});
},
Out: function () {
    var a = this.state.names;
    this.setState({disable: false});
    a.splice(a.length-1,1);
    this.setState({names: a});
},  
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.names.map(function (el) {
                return (<FormRender
                    holder={el.holder}
                    value={el.value}
                    click={el.click}
                    disable={el.disable}
                />);
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/72509/

You have got many syntax errors in you code.
I recommend use linter :)

Comment: Believe it or not, still the same kind of error. Is it a browser problem? I'm testing it with Firefox 51.0.1 .
I would like to know what kind of function is "map" and why you pass, in function In, disable as a new function object instead of "update"
The error seems to be first at {props.holder}