# Default disabled button click event is not firing on reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have button which by default was disabled. But when the checkbox was selected, button will be enabled, using ref i am enabling the button. After the button activated click event is not firing. Without the default disable, button's click event was firing.

```
    class TodoApp extends React.Component {

        onChangeCheckBox(event) {
            if(event.target.checked) {
                this.actionButtonRef.disabled = "";
            }
            else {
                this.actionButtonRef.disabled = "disabled";

            }
        }  

        render() {
            return (
            <div>
                <input 
                    type="checkbox" 
                    ref={element => {
                        this.checkboxAllRef = element;
                    }}
                    onChange={event => this.onChangeCheckBox(event)}/> Checbox 
                <br />
                <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-danger" 
                    ref={element => {
                        this.actionButtonRef = element;
                    }}
                    onClick={event => {
                        alert("clicked");
                    }} 
                    disabled="disabled">Button</button>
            </div>
            )
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

[here is jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sivabalan/en1fax58/)

Comment: Yes i know that we can do with state above code. But i actually want to know why is not working. So i got the answer here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12704

Answer (score 2):

Try this [JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gautamnaik1994/8g3hrbga/2/)

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {      //Set initial state here
      btnDisabled: true
    };
  }
  onChangeCheckBox(event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.setState({ btnDisabled: false }); //Set new state here
    } else {
      this.setState({ btnDisabled: true });  //Set new state here
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={event => this.onChangeCheckBox(event)}
        />{" "}
        Checbox
        <div>
          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-danger"
            onClick={event => {
              alert("clicked");
            }}
            disabled={this.state.btnDisabled}  //Always use state 
          >
            Button
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Your component was not getting rerendered, because u didn't call  **setstate** on click of checkbox.On click of checkbox, u need to call setState and set the **btnDisabled** to **false**.

When setState occurs, reactjs rerenders the component. In doing so, it will make the button enabled.

You should not over use refs in React.

Refs should be used sparingly
Also refer this answer for best practices for disabling button [how-to-disable-button-in-react-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488715/how-to-disable-button-in-react-js/41488965)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that we can done this by using the state. But the problem is, i don't want to re-render the component when the button was disabled/enabled. Is this is the only way to achieve it? And also i what to know the reason why i click event is not triggering. Because i can't find the any reason for it

Comment: @Sivabalan in your question, u were using refs to change the button's disabled attribute, U changed it, by updating the DOM, but react didnt know about it.

Comment: when u clicked on it, react still thought the button is disabled

Comment: By using setstate, u told react to update the DOM. Before that u were updating it urself.

Comment: but when i am changing the textbox value using the ref it was changed without component re-render. Also button was enabled using the ref, but the click event is not triggering. That makes me confused

Comment: @Sivabalan U and I, knows about the button being not disabled, not react, it still things that the button is disabled, and doesnt call onClick

Comment: So i can consider like this, using ref the properties of the element can update but not the events

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169826/discussion-between-sivabalan-and-gautam-naik).

Answer (score 2):

**Manual mutation of DOM elements (actually say virtual DOM) is not allowed by React.**

You need to keep the enabled or disabled state. And work based on the state changes:

Class Constructor:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      checked: false
    };

    this.onChangeCheckBox = this.onChangeCheckBox.bind(this);
    this.onClickButton = this.onClickButton.bind(this);
  }
```

Event Handlers:

```
  onChangeCheckBox(e) {
    this.setState({
      checked: e.target.checked,
    });
  }
  onClickButton(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
```

Render JSX:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.state.checked}
          onChange={this.onChangeCheckBox}
        />
        <button
          type="button"
          disabled={!this.state.checked}
          onClick={this.onClickButton}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/en1fax58/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that we can done this by using the state. But the problem is, i don't want to re-render the component when the button was disabled/enabled. Is this is the only way to achieve it? And also i what to know the reason why i click event is not triggering. Because i can't find the any reason for it

Comment: See the sentence that is on bold. So, if you want not to re-render then you can use shouldComponentUpdate hook while using / updating the state.

Comment: but when i am changing the textbox value using the ref it was changed without component re-render. Also button was enabled using the ref, but the click event is not triggering. That makes me confused

Comment: That's the issue. React will not allow you to work with manual mutation of dom.

Comment: So that i can consider like this. Using the ref we can change the properties but events will not update without re-render

Comment: You just need to accept, changing ref value will not allow you to do so. It's react!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169825/discussion-between-sivabalan-and-bhojendra-nepal).

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the values `true` or `false` as values for the `disabled` property on the button instead of `disabled` and `""`

The button won't properly toggle between disabled and not if these aren't set correctly and therefore you won't be able to do the click event.

On a side note it's usually considered best practice to use refs as little as possible, you could achieve a similar, more desired outcome by using state to toggle between true and false

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it didn't work even changing the values to true and false