# why is React button not calling function on click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

when I changed the disabled of `button` from true to false, it messed my onClick, why is that, and how to solve it?

```js
const Component = () => {
  const refrence = React.useRef(null)
  setTimeout(() => {
    refrence.current.disabled = false
  }, 1000);
  const handleClick = () => console.log('clicked')

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick} ref={refrence} disabled>click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default disabled button click event is not firing on reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024811/default-disabled-button-click-event-is-not-firing-on-reactjs)

Comment: The button is disabled, and thus, not clickable. Did you mean to conditionally disable the button instead?

Comment: @DrewReese the problem is that the onClick callback isn't registered if it is re-enabled manually via ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that the React ref is mutating the DOM, but React isn't made aware of this and so `Component` isn't rerendered with a working button allowing the `onClick` event to go through. This is the main reason why direct DOM manipulations are considered anti-pattern in React.

Additionally, you are setting a timeout to occur every render, though this would have minimal effect it's still unnecessary and would be considered an unintentional side-effect.

## Solution

Use component state and update state in a mounting `useEffect` hook to trigger a rerender.

```
const Component = () => {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsDisabled(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  
  const handleClick = () => console.log('clicked');
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick} disabled={isDisabled}>click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
const Component = () => {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsDisabled(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  
  const handleClick = () => console.log('clicked');
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick} disabled={isDisabled}>click me</button>
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```