# i want to disabled button if textbox null in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mern

```
return (
    {jobstate.jobs.map((data,i) =>{ 
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Post a comment" onChange={(e) => jobcmthandler(e,data._id,i) } />
    <button type="button" onClick={postcmt} >Send</button>
  </form>
   })}
)
```

I generate dynamic HTML using the map function and I want to disabled button if text null for induvial form and also how to get text value on button click in react js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable button in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488715/how-to-disable-button-in-react-js)

Comment: They manage state values for a single from but I have more than 10 form which is generated dynamically so how can I manage state for all form

Comment: @doshismit can you add more code here or codesanbox . It helps other developer to give you more accurate answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really see why you'd want to do this but here you go ([example](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-moser-25kjr?file=/src/App.js:0-600)):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return ["Name", "Age"].map((label) => <Form label={label} />);
}

function Form({ label }) {
  const [readValue, writeValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <form>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Post a comment"
        onChange={(e) => writeValue(e.target.value)}
        value={readValue}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => console.log("Submit")}
        disabled={readValue === ""}
      >
        Send
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```