# Disable onClick event with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to disable a button click using a parameter from a JSON file:

JSON Parameter

```
"reactJson": {
  "disable:"true"
}
```

My current onClick method works fine but if the parameter is true, I want to disable the onClick event. Currently my code looks like this:

```
let myJsonParam = reactJson.disabled //default is false
```

**onClick**

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    handleSumbit();
  }}
>
  Exit and Save
</button>;
```

I know I can do this if it were a boolean:

```
{
  !myJsonParam ? (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        handleSumbit();
      }}
    >
      Exit and Save
    </button>
  ) : (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
      
      }}
    >
      Exit and Save
    </button>
  );
}
```

But since it is a string in JSON `true`is there a different way to disable the button when the string is changed in JSON instead of replicating it and removing the onClick event ?

Comment: JSON or JS object? Consider not putting true/false in a string.

Comment: How do you load the "JSON"? Once it is loaded property, it should be a JavaScript Object and the "true" string should be a `boolean` `true` (but you do not show us how you get your `reactJson` in your code).

Comment: Also, I would suggest having a `disabled` value set on your button instead of having two options (the second option will not look "disabled", it just won't do anything on clicking). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488715/how-to-disable-button-in-react-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you think of this solution?

```
<button
    onClick={() => {
        if (!myJsonParam)
            handleSumbit();
    }}
>
    Exit and Save
</button>
```