# Disable delete button until a new card is created in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I have this component which can add multiple cards with different input values. I have a delete button that deletes the newest card created. I want that delete button to be disabled on click and onkeypress until there's more than one card. The delete button appears to be a valid working button when really it does nothing if there’s only one card. Any help much appreciate it.

Here's my code for the  delete button:

```
 <Button
              onClick={props.deleteCard.bind(null, props.i)}
              aria-label='Remove Card' disabled={props.isLoading}><Icon name='trash' aria/>
            </Button>
```

code for the add new card button:

```
<Button className='btn-confirm'
                                onClick={this.addCard} disabled={!!this.state.loading}>Add Card
                              </Button>
```

functions for both:

```
addCard = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const {particles, errors} = prevState
      particles.push({type: 'constant', distributionType: 'uniform', fields: ['', '']})
      errors.particles.push([null, null, null])

      return {particles, errors}
    })
  }

  deleteCard = (index) => {
    if (this.state.particles.length <= 1) {
      return this.setState((prevState) => {
        const {particles, errors} = prevState
        particles[0] = {type: 'constant', distributionType: 'uniform', fields: ['', '']}
        errors.particles[0] = [null, null, null]

        return {particles, errors}
      })
    }
```

thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488715/how-to-disable-button-in-react-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `disabled` condition to your delete button as follows:

```
            <Button
                onClick={props.deleteCard.bind(null, props.i)}
                aria-label='Remove Card' 
                disabled={props.isLoading || props.particles.length > 1}>
              <Icon name='trash' aria/>
            </Button>
```

Comment: How can I accomplish this when my delete button is in a different file than my state? I'm passing my deleteCard function in props to my delete button. I get error : Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the comment. One way will be to send a prop of the `particles` or  `particles.length` to Button, similarly to how you send `isLoading` as a prop. I'll edit my answer to accommodate the use case.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you!