# Enable-Disable button with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, togglebutton, use-state

I am trying to enable or disable a button based on whether or not there is text in my input but cant seem to achieve it. When I manually set {true OR false} in the disabled property of Button function it works fine but I am really confused on how to set that dynamically based on the content of the input.

Any guidance is super welcome!

This is my app code

```js
import { useState } from "react";

function Input (props){
    const { onChange, value } = props
    return (<input value={value} onChange={onChange} type="text" placeholder="Add a ToDo" maxLength="50"/>)
}

function Button (props) {
    const {onChange, state, text} = props
    return (<button disabled={false} onChange={onChange}>{text}</button>)
}

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [state, setSate] = useState(true);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (!setText(event.target.value)) {
      setSate(false);
    } else {
      setSate(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <Input value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
        <Button onChange={() => handleChange(state)} text="Add" />
        <Button onChange={() => handleChange(state)} text="Clean" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable button in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488715/how-to-disable-button-in-react-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Button` element should change to:

```
function Button (props) {
    const {disabled, onChange, state, text} = props
    return (<button disabled={disabled} onChange={onChange}>{text}</button>)
}
```

Rendering of it should change to:

```
...
<Button disabled={!text} onChange={() => handleBtn()} text="Add" />
...
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-hawking-qqzkw?file=/src/App.js

The idea is to send down `disabled` prop which would be `true` if the there is no text in the field.

ALSO, `handleChange` should look like this:

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };
```

because the rest of your code in that function does not do anything.

Buttons should have their own handler functions .e.g. `const handleBtn = () => {};`

Answer (score 2):

So you should pass the state value you are using to store whatever the users write in the input to the button so that the button knows when the input has text on it or not. And then your second state value can be used to store your todo list, so something like this

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Input({ handleChange, value }) {
  return (
    <input
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      type="text"
      placeholder="Add a Todo"
      maxLength="50"
    />
  );
}

function Button({ handleClick, text, disabled }) {
  return (
    <button disabled={disabled} onClick={handleClick}>
      {text}
    </button>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleAdd = () => {
    setTodoList([...todoList, value]);
    handleClear();
  };

  const handleClear = () => {
    setValue("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <Input value={value} handleChange={handleChange} />
        <Button handleClick={handleAdd} disabled={!value} text="Add" />
        <Button handleClick={handleClear} disabled={!value} text="Clear" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```