# Disable buttons in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

> How can i disable other buttons(AiOutlinePlus) while clicking on one button(AiOutlinePlus)in ReactJS.It should be in the form of one button can be clicked at a time.

```
  <div className="left">
              <hr className="hr"/>
              <div className="left_headers">
                <h2>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h2>
                <i onClick ={()=>setShowLinks(!showLinks)}>
                  <AiOutlinePlus />
                </i>
              </div>
              <p id={showLinks ? "hidden" : ""}>
                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
              </p>
              <button id={showLinks ? "hidden" : ""}xxxxxxxx</button>
              <hr className="hr"/>
              
             <div className="left_headers">
                <h2>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h2>
                <i onClick ={()=>setShowLinks(!showLinks)}>
                  <AiOutlinePlus />
                </i>
              </div>
              <p id={showLinks ? "hidden" : ""}>
                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
              </p>
              <button id={showLinks ? "hidden" : ""}xxxxxxxx</button>
              <hr className="hr"/>
              <div className="left_headers">
                <h2>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h2>
                <i onClick ={()=>setShowLinks(!showLinks)}>
                  <AiOutlinePlus />
                </i>
              </div>
              <p id={showLinks ? "hidden" : ""}>
                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
              </p>
              <button id={showLinks ? "hidden" : ""}xxxxxxxx</button>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass some unique identifier to each button to identify each button. When you click on any one button you need to set a variable in the state which would be used to identify the button clicked. Once the state is updated, you could use it to not set the event handler `onClick` on the other buttons. The same state could also be used to disable the other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Using disabled attribute and state, you can make buttons disabled in Reactjs.

Firstly you have to use the `<button>` HTML tag and use the icons inside it.
The  element has a `disabled` attribute. Below given is a sample component for understanding. Say these are two buttons & here I have used React icons. Clicking the first button disables the second.

```
 class Button extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
     super(props)

    this.state={btn1:false}
    this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(){
   this.setState({btn1: true})
  }
 render(){
  const{btn1}=this.state

     return(

  <div>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}> <AiFillEyeInvisible color="red" size={60}/></button>
    <button disabled={alert1}> <AiFillEye color="green" size={60}/></button>

   </div>
   )
  }
 }
```

If you want to know more check this answer-
[How to disable button in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488715/how-to-disable-button-in-react-js)