# How can make I make the specific button disabled after clicking? - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I created a confirm sell wherein the seller will be able to click a specific transaction in React JS, and once that transaction is complete, the status will be `completed` and the button should be disabled permanently.

[image]

In this latest transaction, I will only confirm the shoe with a status of `pending`

[image: Result]

This is what happened after clicking the pending button.

Confirm Button

```
const confirmSell = async (e) => {
    try {
        await userRequest.put(`/order/${e}`, {status: 'complete'})
        setExecuting(true)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log({error: error.message})
    }
}
```

Actual Button

```
<Button variant="contained" 
   onClick={(e) => confirmSell(recent._id)} 
   disabled={executing} 
   color="success">Confirm 
</Button>
```

Comment: It looks like you already have disabled the button in this code, except maybe you'd want to do so before sending the request, not after (i.e. have `setExecuting(true)` at the beginning of that function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple logic

I assume your products are in JavaScript object

```
products = [
    {
      _id: "1",
      name: "Airpods Wireless Bluetooth Headphones",
      confirmed: "pending",
    },

    {
      _id: "2",
      name: "iPhone 11 Pro 256GB Memory",
      confirmed: "pending",
    },
]
```

What should be done is to check the status, if completed disable the button, if not enable the button

```
 {products.map(product => (
      <tr>
      <td>
        {product.confirmed == 'completed' ? <button disabled className='btn btn-primary'>Confirm</button> : <button className='btn btn-primary'>Confirm</button>}
        </td>
    </tr>   
))}
```

After that implementation your table should look like this

[image: This image shows your final view]

NOTE: Remember to get product id and handle confirm event once user click confirm

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you can do something like this:

```
<Button id="submit" variant="contained" 
   onClick={(e) => confirmSell(recent._id)} 
   disabled={executing} 
   color="success">Confirm 
</Button>
```

```js
const confirmSell = async (e) => {
    try {
        await userRequest.put(`/order/${e}`, {status: 'complete'})
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log({error: error.message})
    }
}
```

OR

You can check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41488965/12271495, I would recommend this example that I linked.